# Show that differential cross section is independent of $θ$ for elastic scattering

Tags: homework-and-exercises, collision, scattering-cross-section

I have two hard sphere which took part in elastic scattering, I have attached a diagram below and I have assumed here that since its is elastic the angle of incidence $\alpha$ is equal to the angle of reflection $\alpha$

$b=(r_1+r_2 )\sin⁡(\pi/2-\theta/2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$\sin(2x)=2\sin (x) \cos (x)$$

If $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)>0$:

$$\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\Bigg|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\Bigg|=\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta,$$

so the $\sin\theta$ cancels with the one on the denominator. If $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)<0:$

$$\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\Bigg|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\Bigg|=-\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta,$$

the same applies. There is a change in the sign, but $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$ is always positive in $[0,2\pi]$, so $\sigma$ is independent of $\theta$.